# How do I search for and keep only a series of duplicate words in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a long `.txt` file, here's a sample:

```
A Beautiful Mind (Howard, 2001) Blu-ray, RIP, 1080p, x264, AC3 ITA-ENG, Subs, MKV, 12.26  
A Bigger Splash (Guadagnino, 2015) Blu-ray, RIP, 1080p, x264, DTS ITA, Subs, MKV, 7.93  
A casa con i miei (D. Lee, 2008) WEB, RIP, 1080p, x264, E-AC3/AAC ITA, E-AC3/AAC ENG, Subs, MKV  
A casa con i suoi (Dey, 2006) Blu-ray, RIP, 1080p, x264, AC3 ITA-ENG, Subs, MKV, 8.57  
A casa per le vacanze (Foster, 1995) Blu-ray, FOUND, 1080p, x264, AC3 ITA, MKV, 1.79  
A casa per Natale (Brolin, 2016) WEB, RIP, 1080p, x264, E-AC3 ITA, Subs, MKV, 1.74  
A casa per Natale (Fall, 2013) WEB, MUX, 1080p, x264, AC3 ITA, MKV, 2.68  
A casa per Natale (Sanford, 1998) Blu-ray, MUX, 1080p, x264, AC3 ITA, MKV, 1.73  
A casa tutti bene (Muccino, 2018) Blu-ray, RIP, 1080p, x264, DTS ITA, Subs, MKV, 5.71  
A cavallo della tigre (Comencini, 1961) WEB, RIP, 1080p, x264, AAC/E-AC3 ITA, Subs, MKV, 10.44  
A cena con un cretino (Roach, 2010) Blu-ray, RIP, 1080p, x264, AC3 ITA-ENG, Subs, MKV, 8.36  
A Christmas Carol (Zemeckis, 2009) Blu-ray 3D, Half-SBS, RIP, 1080p, x264, AC3 ITA, AAC ENG, MKV  
A Christmas Carol (Zemeckis, 2009) Blu-ray, RIP, 1080p, x264, DTS ITA, AC3 ENG, Subs, MKV, 4.51  
A Christmas Melody (Carey, 2015) WEB, MUX, 1080p, x264, AC3 ITA, MKV, 1.70  
A Christmas Reunion (Olson, 2015) WEB, MUX, 1080p, x264, AC3 ITA, MKV, 1.75  
A Christmas wish (Clyde , 2011) WEB, RIP, 1080p, x264, AAC ITA, MKV, 1.85  
A Ciambra (Carpignano, 2017) Blu-ray, FOUND, 1080p, x264, DTS ITA, Subs, MKV, 13.39  
A ciascuno il suo (Petri, 1967) Blu-ray, RIP, 1080p, x264, DTS/AAC ITA, AC3 GER, Subs, MKV, 8.82  
A Classic Horror Story (De Feo/Strippoli, 2021) WEB, FOUND, 1080p, x264, E-AC3/AAC ITA, Subs  
A Dangerous Method (Cronenberg, 2011) Blu-ray, RIP, 1080p, x264, DTS ITA, AAC ENG, Subs, MKV  
A Ghost Story (Lowery, 2017) Blu-ray, RIP, 1080p, x264, DTS ITA, AC3 ENG, Subs, MKV, 9.02  
A Good Marriage (Askin, 2014) Blu-ray, RIP, 1080p, x264, DTS ITA, AC3 ENG, Subs, MKV, 7.00  
A History of Violence (Cronenberg, 2005) Blu-ray, RIP, 1080p, x264, DTS ITA, AC3 ENG, Subs, MKV  
À l'intérieur (Bustillo/Maury, 2007) Blu-ray, RIP, 1080p, x264, DTS ITA, AC3 FRE, Subs, MKV, 4.61  
A letto con il nemico (Ruben, 1991) Blu-ray, RIP, 1080p, x264, DTS ITA, AC3 ENG, Subs, MKV, 7.44  
A mano disarmata (Bonivento, 2019) Blu-ray, RIP, 1080p, x264, DTS ITA, Subs, MKV, 6.37  
A mezzanotte va la ronda del piacere (Fondato, 1975) DVB, RIP, 1080p, x264, E-AC3/AAC ITA, Subs  
A Modern Family (Fleming, 2018) Blu-ray, RIP, 1080p, x264, DTS ITA, AC3 ENG, Subs, MKV, 6.80
```

The objective is to mark lines that have the same title, I mean if more than 1 line has the same series of words that (not case sensitive), until the `)` char, then mark the line. So I then delete all the unbookmarked lines keeping only lines with duplicates titles.

Can this be done with Notepad++ regex search?

Whatever other simple solutions are appreciated.

Comment: I think that spreadsheets or better regex handlers (like `grep` or `awk`) are better suited than Notepad++.

Comment: Hi,. mark which line? Only the duplicates or the duplicates and "original" too?

Comment: And can the duplicates be separated by few lines? I assume not since they look to be sorted, but just making sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- Find what: `(^.+?\)).+$(?:\R\1.+$)+`
- **TICK** `Bookmark lines`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Mark all</kbd>
- Search menu > Bookmark
- Remove Unmarked Lines

**Explanation:**

```
(           # group 1
  ^           # beginning of line
    .+?         # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    \)          # closong parenthesis
)           # end group 1
.+          # 1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
(?:         # non capture group
    \R          # any kind of linebreak
    \1          # backreference to group 1
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
    $           # end of line
)+          # end group, must appear 1 or more times
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works great!